# Why do I get an access violation while reading the pixels of an SDL_Surface as follows?

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to write a software rasterizer and I'm in the step to texture a triangle. I'm trying to get a pixel from an `SDL_Surface` which is an image, 100x60 at 24 bits of color depth.

I got a read access violation exception. For instance I try to say

```
Uint32 * pixels = (Uint32 *)texture->pixels;
```

then

```
int pixel = pixels[5900];
```

It gives an access violation. However the calculated pixels count is correct

```
int pixel_count  = (texture->pitch / texture->format->BytesPerPixel) * texture->h;
```

Is this wrong? How can I access the pixels of this surface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're reading off the end of the 24-bit data, because you're treating it as if it was 32-bit.

That is I suspect texture->pitch is 300 and texture->format->BytesPerPixel is 3. sizeof(Uint32) is of course 4.

The simplest solution is to use a 32-bit image.

Comment: Thanks so much!, but I was thinking about how would I work out a solution If I want to use a 24bit image ? I should encode the resultant pixel to a 32bit pixel ?
also why I read the end of the 24bit data ? isn't 5900 is still in the range of 100*60 W*H ?

Comment: Your surface array is 24bit*60*100 = 18000 byte long. You access the 32bit*5900 = 23600th byte, which is out of bounds.

Comment: @LuisW Thanks. The problem original with the casting.